# Target object nested inside "this"-statement referenced object in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a clickable dropdown menu interface for a menu page. Clicking on a section heading will reveal the list of links in that section.

For each section heading I want to include a "+" if the section can be expanded, and a "-" if the section can be collapsed. Since each section heading includes specific text, I want to include this symbol in its own span that I can target with Jquery. So the setup looks like this:

```
<h1 class="sectionHeader"><span class="sectionMarker"></span>  This is Section 1</h1>
```

There is nothing in the span tags because Jquery will be adding that at runtime.

The actual section menu is stored in a separate div below the h1 tag, which I know to target with $(this).next('.divClass'), but I cannot figure out how to target that span tag within the h1 tag. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `find()` to **find** the `span` tag in the **h1** as stated in [the docs:](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

`$(this).find('span')`

will get the `span` that is in the `h1` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the find method

```
$(this).find('.sectionMarker')
```